# Binding content of one Radio button in group 2 with selected radio button in group 1

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding

I have two groups of radio button in my WPF xaml.

```
<StackPanel Margin="5,-4,0,5">
 <RadioButton Content="abc" GroupName="grp1" IsChecked="true" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
 <RadioButton Content="def" GroupName="grp1" IsChecked="false" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
</StackPanel>


<StackPanel Margin="5,-4,0,5">
 <RadioButton Content="{Binding ElementName}" GroupName="grp2" IsChecked="true" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
 <RadioButton Content="xyz" GroupName="grp2" IsChecked="false" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>                         
</StackPanel>
```

I want to bind the content of grp2 radiobutton with SelectedName in grp1 radiobuttons.
For eg: if abc radiobutton is selected in grp1, then name of first radiobutton should be Value_***, where *** is abc or def depending on the radio button selected.

Thanks,
Rohit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
<StackPanel Margin="5,-4,0,5">
        <RadioButton Content="abc" GroupName="grp1" x:Name="AbcRadioBtn" IsChecked="true" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
        <RadioButton Content="def" GroupName="grp1" x:Name="DefRadioBtn" IsChecked="false" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Margin="5,-4,0,5">
        <RadioButton GroupName="grp2" IsChecked="true" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5">
            <RadioButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AbcRadioBtn, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True
                                     ">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ElementName=AbcRadioBtn,Path=Content}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DefRadioBtn, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ElementName=DefRadioBtn,Path=Content}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RadioButton.Style>
        </RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="xyz" GroupName="grp2" IsChecked="false" Margin=" 8,-4,8,5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind both to a DependencyProperty in your ViewModel.